# method to load JSON file which returns JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a JavaScript method/function or a way of creating a method/function to load a JSON file, which will instead of requiring a callback parameter to run after the file is loaded, simply wait and then return the JSON object once fully loaded (WITHOUT a library)?

For example, if my file `something.json` contains the following:

```
{
    "name":"John Smith",
    "age":"40"
}
```

And my JavaScript (on the same server) was as follows:

```
var person = loadJsonFile("something.json");
console.log("Name: " + person.name);
console.log("Age:  " + person.age);
```

My console will read:

```
Name: John Smith
Age:  40
```

I can't use async because this is within a function and I can't say for sure what the results of the method are going to be used for. Also I can't because all the methods after the loading call depend on the return of that call, and there are many that I can't put into another function because of the function's scope.

Comment: To run in the browser? You don't want this. The user's browser will appear to lock-up until your server returns a response.

Comment: Why do you need it to be synchronous?

Comment: You should change your question to ask what you're really trying to do because this is  the wrong way to do it. This feels like an XY Problem http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: If you are in the browser, you could do this without locking it up by using a synchronous ajax inside a web worker. It's a very big gun if the issue is just programming convenience though.

Comment: See [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: *" I can't say for sure what the results of the method are going to be used for"* So, this is an integration with a third party API? Because usually if you define the function, you can also define how people are supposed to use it.

Comment: I cannot because I am making a tool and every function called and everything else done in the page is waiting for this to be done, and can't happen or even be loaded until this method is done, because this method loads a list of all other javascript dependencies to load.

Comment: I suggest you don't try to reinvent the wheel, and instead use a well-established dependency loader, as [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it might be possible to load the JSON file synchronously. The [3rd argument of the `open` method of `XMLHTTPRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29) is a Boolean: if you set it to `false`, the `send` method does not return until the response is received.

There are two serious problems with this: first, the browser will hang until the response arrives, and second, some browsers always do an asynchronous request, independently of this argument (e.g. Firefox 30+). Don't be afraid of async, use a callback. You can connect callbacks in series if you have to, see for example [here](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html) (this book is about Node.js, but the techniques mentioned on this page can be used in client-side JavaScript, too).

To be honest, I used this approach once, when I had to port a Firefox extension to Chrome. I wanted to implement the function [`require`](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1#Module_Context), which loads JavaScripts modules synchronously, and this approach was the only way I could figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like this (portions copied, credit given):

```
function loadJsonFile(file)
{
    "use strict";
    //THIS PORTION IS COPIED FROM: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_asyncfalse
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",file,false); //modified
    xmlhttp.send();
    //END COPIED PORTION
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```